# Can't stop execution of "ADD PERIOD"

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to conditionally execute an `ALTER TABLE` command ([this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/09/20/persisting-job-history-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/), to be precise).  However, I can't get the `ADD PERIOD` to be conditional and I suspect this might be a bug.

Here's what I've tried to skip execution if the `PERIOD` already exists on the table.  All of these raise the same error:

> Msg 13597, Level 16, State 2, Line xx
>
> Temporal SYSTEM_TIME period is already defined on table 'msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory'.

1. Only add the `PERIOD` if it doesn't currently exist:

   ```
   if not exists(select 1 from sys.periods where object_id = OBJECT_ID('sysjobhistory'))
       ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
       ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)
   ```

   This raised the error.
2. Since the above didn't work, I wanted to make sure my `IF` statement was evaluating correctly so I tried:

   ```
   if 1=2
       ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
       ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)
   ```

   But that raised the error as well.
3. Use `SET NOEXEC ON` to [stop execution of the code](http://sqlhints.com/2015/05/23/how-to-stop-or-abort-or-break-the-execution-of-the-statements-in-the-current-batch-and-in-the-subsequent-batches-separated-by-go-statement-based-on-some-condition-in-sql-server/):

   ```
   set noexec ON
       ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
       ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)
   set noexec OFF
   ```

   Didn't work.  The `ALTER TABLE` still raised the error.
4. Admit defeat and wrap it in a `TRY/CATCH` and just ignore the error:

   ```
   begin try
       ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
       ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)
   end try
   begin catch
   end catch
   ```

   This raised the error too -- which I didn't expect since it was a level 16 and, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017#error-severity-and-trycatch), a level 16 should go to the `CATCH` block.

Is this a bug in Azure SQL Server?  This is running on a Managed Instance.  The `@@VERSION` reports:

> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov  2 2018 21:17:06   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

**UPDATE**:

I can use a similar technique to skip adding columns that already exist without any issues:

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.columns where name = 'StartTime' and object_id = OBJECT_ID('sysjobhistory'))
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
    ADD StartTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT ('19000101 00:00:00.0000000')
GO
```

The above code only executes if the `sysjobhistory` does not contain the column `StartTime`.  If it already does, the code does nothing and continues executing.  The `ALTER TABLE` with `ADD PERIOD` always causes an execution error even if the code is inside an `IF` condition that evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for DDL like this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.periods WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('sysjobhistory'))
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    SET @sql += N'
    ALTER TABLE dbo.sysjobhistory
    ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime);'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: @PatrickSteele ADD COLUMN and ADD CONSTRAINT appear to get deferred compilation whereas ADD PERIOD doesn't. I don't find any documentation stating this behaviour though for any of them. I guess technically not a bug as it isnt behaving differently from how it is documented to work.

Answer (score 2):

Statement processing happens in several consecutive phases. Fist comes parsing, then binding, then optimization and finally execution.

I suspect your problem originates at the binding phase. Here SQL Server maps tokens from the statement to objects in the database. Since it finds existing objects for the ones it is trying to create it throws and error. Why the development team chose to implement this branch of ALTER TABLE in binding rather than execution only they can say.

The solution, as Erik says, is to use dynamic SQL. This  creates a new "inner" batch which is only submitted for processing during the execution phase of the "outer" batch. Hence the checks are sure to pass (absent concurrent changes).